# $stateParams is not passing params in $scope.$on method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to fit routing in existing application. It requires too much changes to fit router in perfect manner so I'm trying to manage it using `$broadcast` and `onEnter` of ui-router.

I'm changing `URL` using `$state.go` and passing parameters. I'm able to get correct `$stateParams` inside `onEnter` method but when I broadcast event from there, it's executing that event which is registered inside a controller but inside that I'm not getting updated `$stateParams` object.

```
$stateProvider.state("state1", {
    url: "/state1/{docId}",
    template: "<p>State 1</p>",

  }).state("state2", {
    url: "/state2/{docId}",
    template: "<p >State 2</p>",
    onEnter : function($rootScope,$stateParams) {
        console.log("Before braodcast ", JSON.stringify($stateParams));
        $rootScope.$broadcast("getDataForState2");
    }
  });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6gqfz96/5/) Showing my problem. Click on state 2 and have a look at console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use timeout in your .$on()

```
$scope.$on("getDataForState2",function() {
    $timeout(function(){
        console.log(JSON.stringify($stateParams));
    });
})
```

Comment: this solves your problem, but I won't suggest this method. I would rather suggest you to use resolve.

Comment: I know that's the proper way but for now I just want to make it work so thanks for your quick help.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the relevant data in the event

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('getDataForState2', $stateParams);
```

and handle it in your listener

```
$scope.$on('getDataForState2', function(e, $stateParams) {
    console.log($stateParams);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a6gqfz96/6/